# access element component silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, code-behind

I'm developing a player based on Silverlight 5 on MVVM pattern. I'm trying to change status buttons in code behind.

File : **PlayerPage.xaml** 
My player component xaml :

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <player:Player x:Name="Player"
                   Playlist="{Binding Playlist}"
                   CurrentPlaylistItem="{Binding CurrentPlaylistItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   IsSeekingEnabled="{Binding CanSeek}"
                   AutoLoad="True"
                   AutoPlay="True"
                   MediaEnded="Player_MediaEnded"
                   MediaOpened="Player_MediaOpened"
                   Style="{StaticResource PlayerStyle}"
                   PlaylistVisibility="Disabled"
                   LogLevel="Warning"
                   AutoHideControls="True"
                   AutoHideDelay="0:0:5"
                   AllowDoubleClickToggle="True"
                   RetryDuration="00:01:00"
                   RetryInterval="00:00:10"
                   BufferingTime="00:00:15"
        />

</Grid>
```

File : **PlayerPage.xaml** 
Style of component player :

```
<Grid x:Name="ControllerContainer" Height="40" Grid.Row="4"    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
   <Grid.RenderTransform>
       <CompositeTransform />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
               <Grid.Background>
                   <ImageBrush ImageSource="component/Images/grid_background_player.jpg"
                                    AlignmentY="Top" />
                         </Grid.Background>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid x:Name="playercontrols" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="90">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Button x:Name="TbPlayElement" Click="TbPlayElement_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand" >
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Image Source="component/Resources/play.png" Stretch="Uniform" Height="16" Width="16" />
                                                </Grid>
                                    </Button>
```

Now in my code behind **PlayerPage.cs**, when I press the stop button, I want to change the image of the play button.

```
 private void TbStopElement_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

How can I access the play button in code behind ?

Comment: Bind the source of the Image to a property of type BitmapImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach to the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event to save a reference of the image:

xaml:

```
<Image Source="component/Resources/play.png" Stretch="Uniform" Height="16" Width="16"
       Loaded="ImageLoaded" />
```

code-behind:

```
private Image imageReference;
private void ImageLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imageReference = sender as Image;
}
```

Then when you want to change the image:

```
private void TbStopElement_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(imageReference != null)
    {
        imageReference.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/YourAppName;component/Resources/YourImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this code

```
TbPlayElement.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/TbPlayElement.content;component/NameNewImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Remark : Check properties in Visual Studio for the xaml file,ensure that `Build Action is set to Page`.

Or you can use ToggleButton

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I tested this code, but the button or image is not recognized by visual studio and I can not reach its properties and so I have no compilation.

Comment: it's your image control for property, but for path, you must add image file, ensure that's image is in your repository

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My images are betting resources, my problem is that I can not get their hands on this button or image

Comment: Replace the playButtonImage with TbPlayElement (Because it's id of your object typed button)

Comment: is the same. I can not access it. I can not have access to elements of the player in the code behind. full xaml page : http://pastebin.com/Tk7JSZCT

Comment: sorry i can't acces your post

Comment: I put this file on github https://gist.github.com/flug/7704190/raw/31e4e569f6a8c9a694d93355b806d9ce5d74c283/playerpage.xaml

Comment: Visual Studio shows in Error List : "Error 8 The name 'TbPlayElement' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Check properties in Visual Studio for the xaml file,ensure that Build Action is set to Page.

Answer (score 1):

Access in your `TbStopElement` like this:

```
        var grid = TbPlayElement.Content as Grid;
        var playImage = grid.Children[0] as Image;

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("newImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
        playImage.Source = bitmap;
```

Comment: Thank, I try you code and bitmap.Beginit and bitmap.endInit don't exist, and I don't access have PlayImage x:name. This is my problem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot it is `WPF` specific. I'll update accordingly. Could you try without those methods?

Comment: @Flug When you say, you don't have access to PlayImage x:Name, did you mean you don't have access to source code?

Comment: @Flug Now you can access without x:name. I had changed  to code sample.